# How to get count of all the files of different extension type present in a directory and all its subdirectories using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I need to count all the files present in a directory and all its subdirectory with specific file extensions using shell script. Ex: I want a count of all the .py and .sh files in a directory and its subsequent subdirectories.

Sorry I missed to put in that
I started with

```
find . -type f | sed -n 's/..*\.//p' | sort | uniq -c
```

but this is not printing anything

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: See [How can I get a count of files in a directory using the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1125/264812).

Comment: @Cyrus sorry I missed to put that part ...

Comment: Your current find command finds all files not just the .py and .sh files.   You could start by amending your find to something like `find . -type f \( -name "*.py" -o -name "*.sh" \)`

Comment: Notice that unix files don't have extension

Comment: Also see [Is there a bash command which counts files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11307257/4154375), [Recursively counting files in a Linux directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9157138/4154375), [Script to find recursively the number of files with a certain extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69988369/4154375), and [BashFAQ/004 (How can I check whether a directory is empty or not? How do I check for any *.mpg files, or count how many there are?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004).

Comment: It's not clear from your question, whether you know in advance what "extension" you want to look at (i.e. `.py`), or whether your program needs to find out what "extensions" exist in your directory tree and then produces a count for **all** of them.

Comment: I want to consider all the extensions that are available in a directory and its subdirectory

Answer (score 1):

To get all the extensions counted:

```
find . -type f -print | awk -F . '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

If you want to limit the type of files, you can add `-name` options to the `find` command.

```
find . -type f -name "*\.txt" -print | awk -F . '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

You can combine multiple `-name` options like this:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*\.txt" -o -name "*\.pdf" \) -print | awk -F . '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

The last `sort -n` lists the extensions in increasing order.